# OpenOPC.open_client() hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, plc, opc, open-opc

I'm trying to connect to an OPC Server using the python Open OPC library, it is working fine with a Matrikon OPC Simulator, however when I try to connect it to the actual server the client seems to be hanging on the OpenOPC.open_client method, I added some debug messages in this API and found that the following API in OpenOPC.py is hanging:

```
import Pyro.core
Pyro.core.initClient(banner=0)
server_obj = Pyro.core.getProxyForURI("PYROLOC://%s:%s/opc" % (host, port))
return server_obj.create_client() #this API is hanging
```

So if anyone has used OpenOPC to interface with OPC Servers, and has run into similar problem, please let me know.
 cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a OPC UA or a OPC Da server..?

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse Its an OPC DA Server. Thanks!

Comment: Have you done all the DCOM settings on both the client and the server machines?

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse thats a problem coz i'm trying to use a Linux OPC Client, and I'm not quite sure if DCOM settings is applicable for this, at-least I couldn't find anything in the OpenOPC API, if there is a way to do it, please let me know.! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When using OpenOPC in Linux, you can't use DCOM.

So you need to use OpenOPC Gateway Service and the "open_client" method.

This service must be installed and running in the actual OPC server for your client to access it.